# Will a single Node process program gain any performance running on multi-core container?

Tags: node.js

I understand that Node.js application runs on a single thread but will mostly hand off async operations (e.g. I/O) to OS which could run in multiple threads.

My question is could these multi-threads operations be running on multi-cores as well? If that's the case, does this mean I can still gain performance by running a single node process on a multi-core container? Is there any merit of running a single node application on a multi-core container?

Comment: I/O depends on the number of I/O channels the CPU has, in modern desktop and server CPUs this means PCI lanes. I/O does not depend on the number of cores the CPU has because I/O does not run on threads - they are handled by the hardware. Only when the hardware is fully busy does the OS make I/O take turns using the PCI lanes the same way the OS make threads take turns using cores. For network I/O it depends on how many network cards you have (trunking). Otherwise network I/O are serialized into a single bit stream because that's what the wire can carry

Comment: Do note that the number of PCI lanes the CPU has is usually related to the number of cores. That's just how Intel and AMD manufacture CPUs. So if you want max node.js performance it may still make sense to get a 64 core Threadripper even though you will only be using 1 core because you want the PCI lanes for high speed disk I/O in a RAID array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is could these multi-threads operations be running on multi-cores as well?

Nodejs does have some native threads that could benefit from multiple cores, particularly for things like crypto operations.

Network I/O is all natively asynchronous so it doesn't really benefit.

Disk I/O uses a thread pool, but the threads are mostly blocked waiting for system I/O once a disk operation is started so there might be a small benefit, but not a large one.  The main reason for the thread pool is to give a synchronous OS operation an asynchronous interface to preserve the asynchronous I/O model of nodejs.

> If that's the case, does this mean I can still gain performance by running a single node process on a multi-core container? Is there any merit of running a single node application on a multi-core container?

It really depends upon what your app is doing.  If performance is mostly limited by your own CPU-intensive Javascript execution or by network I/O, then you won't really benefit much from other CPU cores because of the single-threadedness of Javascript execution and the natively asynchronous networking I/O.  If, on the other hand, you were doing a bunch of crypto operations that nodejs pushes off to threads, then you might benefit significantly.

If your container contains other processes such as a database, then that likely will benefit from other cores.

In a generic sense, you would probably get a small benefit just from the few things that nodejs uses native threads for that might see some benefit, but I wouldn't expect it to be a large effect.

---

In the end, the true answer to this question for your specific application can only be answered by testing.  Create a reproducible specific load on your server that is representative of the types of things your app does and then test with a single-core container vs. a multi-core container.